# Efficient Method for Calculating the Probability of a Set of Outcomes?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, statistics, probability, dynamic-programming

Let's say I'm playing 10 different games.  For each game, I know the probability of winning, the probability of tying, and the probability of losing (each game has different probabilities).

From these values, I can calculate the probability of winning X games, the probability of losing X games, and the probability of tying X games (for X = 0 to 10).

I'm just trying to figure out the probability of winning *W* games, tying *T* games, and losing *L* games after playing all 10 games... and hopefully do better than O(3^n).  For example, what is the probability of winning 7, losing 2, and tying 1?

Any ideas? Thanks!

---

Edit - here's some example data for if there were only 2 games:

Game 1:

- win: 23.3%
- tie: 1.1%
- lose: 75.6%

Game 2:

- win: 29.5%
- tie: 3.2%
- lose: 67.3%

Based on this, we can calculate the probability after playing 2 games of:

---

- 0 wins: 54.0%
- 1 win: 39.1%
- 2 wins: 6.9%

---

- 0 ties: 95.8%
- 1 tie: 4.2%
- 2 ties: 0.0%

---

- 0 losses: 8.0%
- 1 loss: 41.1%
- 2 losses: 50.9%

---

Based on these numbers, is there a generic formula for finding the probability of *W* wins, *T* ties, and *L* losses?  The possible outcomes (W-L-T) would be:

- 2-0-0
- 1-1-0
- 1-0-1
- 0-1-1
- 0-2-0
- 0-0-2

Comment: Well, can you tell us if the games _are_ independent? If not, how do they depend on each other?

Comment: @Kenny. OK, see my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Could you provide the probabilities of a win, a tie, and a loss for a single game?

Comment: added some sample data for 2 games above

Comment: Oh, CRAP! OK, both Alexander and I are assuming that each game has exactly the same probabilities. If each game has a different chance of win loss or tie, then everything's different.

Comment: yep :-) sorry for the confusion.  any other ideas?

Comment: New edits in my answer. In short, you'll have to do it the long way :(

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was afraid of that... still hoping there might be a tricky dynamic-programming way to solve this efficiently.

Comment: Off hand I'd say there probably is. Many permutations share common pieces, so you can save off those bits and reuse them. I'd try an algorithm that split in half and each time checked for a saved calculation for that half. If there isn't one, subdivide in half again until you're at one game or you have a saved calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with dynamic programming, I'm not sure if there is a better method as the games are independent.

Have a 4-D array, of wins, losses, ties, and games. You can limit wins/losses/ties to the number you want (let these be W, L, T, W+L+T=G) , time complexity will be O(W*L*T*G), which is bounded by O(G⁴).

The algorithm is basically:

```
A[][][][] = new double[G+1][W][T][L]
// A[g][w][t][l] is the probability of have w wins, t ties, l losses
// after g games. This can be computed from A[g-1].
// Let P[g][o] be the probability of outcome o for game g
//everything else is initially 0.
A[0][0][0][0] = 1
for g=1..G
 for w=0..W
  for t=0..T
   for l=0..L
    A[g][w][t][l] = A[g-1][w-1][t][l]*P[g][win] // assume out of bounds
                   +A[g-1][w][t-1][l]*P[g][tie] // reference returns 0
                   +A[g-1][w][t][l-1]*P[g][lose]
return A[G][W][T][L]
```

**edit)**

We can do this in O(W*L*T*G/max(W,L,T)), i.e. O(G³). Note that if we have W wins and T ties after G games, then we must have L losses.

```
// we should pick the conditions we loop to be the smallest two.
// here we just use wins and ties.
A[][][][] = new double[G+1][W][T]
A[0][0][0] = 1
for g=1..G
 for w=0..W
  for t=0..T
   A[g][w][t] = A[g-1][w-1][t]*P[g][win] // assume out of bounds
               +A[g-1][w][t-1]*P[g][tie] // reference returns 0
               +A[g-1][w][t]*P[g][lose]
return A[G][W][T]
```

Maybe it's possible to do this significantly faster, by computing the probabilities of x wins/ties/losses separately (O(G)), and then adding/subtracting them intelligently, but I haven't found a way to do this.

Comment: This sounds promising, but can you elaborate a little bit more on your algorithm?  I'm not sure I follow how to implement it.  Thanks! :-)

Comment: I don't see a reason for doing it in O(N^3). See my response. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Eyal The win/tie/loss odds vary for each game, so you can't use the basic statistics approach.

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice that the probabilities are changing.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, you need to consider the possible ways that the outcome can occur.

For win 7, lose 2, tie 1. There are `10! / (2!*7!)` or 360 possible ways. So multiply all the outcomes as you did, then multiply by that many permutations of the outcomes.

For all wins, you can just multiply because there's exactly one permutation of ten wins. For a mix, you need to consider the permutation.

In general for this problem the permutations will be `10!/(w!*l!*t!)` where w is number of wins, l is number of losses, and t is number of ties.

**Edit 1** 
Note that the above only indicates how to count the permutations. The total probability is the number of permutations times (pw^w*pl^l*pt^t) where pw is probability of a win, pl a loss, pt a tie. w, l, and t, are the counts of each.

**Edit 2**
OK, in light of the new information, I don't know of a general way to do this. You'll have to individually computer each outcome by hand and add them together. With your two-game example above. If you want to find the probability of 1 win and 1 tie, you'll have to find every possible way of getting exactly 1 win and exactly one tie (there are only two) and add them up.

For ten games with the initial example, you'll have 360 outcomes that meet your criteria. You'll have to do each permutation and add up the probabilities. (wwwwwwwllt, wwwwwwwltl, etc) Unfortunately, I don't know of a better way to do this.

Further, in your two-game example, for one win and one tie, you must add the probability of winning the first game and tying the second to the probability of tying first, then winning.

So, there are nine independent outcomes:

```
W W
W T
W L
T W
T T
T L
L W
L T
L L
```

Comment: Here's the problem. Let's consider the case of 10 wins, 0 losses, and 0 ties

This probability of going 10-0-0 SHOULD be the same as the probability of getting 10 wins that I've already calculated (since there is only 1 way to get 10 wins).  However, your formula would have me multiply this probability TIMES the probability of getting 0 losses and then multiply again times the probability of getting 0 ties (which will both be extremely small numbers)

Comment: Ah, not quite. My equations here are only to determine the number of permutations. The w, l, and t, are no probabilities. I should expand on that, but my intent is to calculate the probability he did (and you have as O in your first equation), then multiply that number by the total count of permutations. So, you'd take O (exactly as you have it, I agree completely), then multiply by 360. In the case of ten wins, 0 losses, and 0 ties, there is exactly one permutation, so you'd multiply by one (10!/(10!*0!*0!) = 1).

Comment: right but in that case, wouldn't O be too small?  The probability of going 10-0-0 and is just probability of getting 10 wins... not the probability of getting 10 wins TIMES the probability of getting 0 losses TIMES the probability of getting 0 ties.

Comment: You may misunderstand. For ten wins O = pw^10*pl^0*pt^0 = pw^10*1*1 = pw^10. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, now I see the confusion.  The probability of winning each game is a different known probability (think of them as different types of games), which is why I can't simply do pw^10.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Was hoping there might be an algorithm better than O(3^n) :-/

Answer (score 1):

My area, statistics!

You need to calculate the odds of one permutation, which can be done as so:

```
O = chanceWin^numWin * chanceTie^numTie * chanceLose^numLose
```

where numWin, numLose and numTie are 7, 2 and 1, as per your example.

Now multiply by the permutations for winning, which is:

```
O *= 10! / ((10-numWin)! * numWin!)
```

then losing:

```
p = 10-numWin
O *= p! / ((p-numLose)! * numLose!)
```

then tying:

```
p = 10-(numWin+numLose)
O *= p! / ((p-numTie)! * numTie!)
```

Now O is the odds of you winning numWin games, losing numLose games and tying numTie games out of 10 games.

Comment: I'm curious if we're getting to the same answer or not. Do you find that there are 360 permutations for the above example ( 7, 2, 1)?

Comment: Yeah I think we're on the right track, but if I sum up the probabilities for all the possible outcomes, I'm getting values significantly greater than 1 for both this method and Josh's.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run over the 3^n options, you can **approximate** the answer by using **sampling**: decide on N, the number of times you wish to sample. Run N samples, and count how many results of each type you had (0 wins, 1 win, etc). The approximate probability of each outcome is number_of_samples_resulting_this_outcome / N.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**

The response below is only valid when the win/lose probabilities are *fixed* through the series of games. I misunderstood the conditions. I leave it anyway as a solution for the simpler case.

I got this formula for W wins, L loses, and N-W-L ties:

[image]

**Complexity of computation**

Each one of the powers and factorials has at most an order of N, so the value can be computed in **linear time**, unless I am missing some requirement.

The following Java code works for me. I also validated that the probabilities sum to 1:

```
public static double p(int w, int l, int t, double pw, double pl) {
    double r = factorial(w+l+t) * Math.pow(pw,w) * Math.pow(pl,l) * Math.pow(1-pw-pl, t);
    r /= factorial(w) * factorial(l) * factorial(t);
    return r;
}

private static long factorial(int n) {
    long res = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        res *= i;

    return res;
}
```